# Get the correct value from locations field

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the theme Jobcareer to show jobs on the website. Every job has it's location (city). But when I want to display the value from location it's showing the slug instead of the real value.

This is the code I have:

```
$vt_city = get_post_meta($cs_job_id, 'cs_post_loc_city', true);

echo $vt_city;
```

This will result in showing the slug "city-name" instead of the value "City Name".

Comment: what are you getting when you `var_dump($vt_city)` ?

Comment: Then it's showing: string(9) "amsterdam". What should be "Amsterdam".

Comment: than it is working fine :D

Comment: Yes, but it's showing the "slug" instead of the "value". That's not good.

Comment: i am sorry i dont know meaning of "slug", could you explain it ?

Comment: The slug is the URL-friendly name of the value, if the value is "My City name" then the slug is "my-city-name".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185816/discussion-between-nullpoite-and-n00bly).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then you want it camel cased and replace `-` with space.

```
echo ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $vt_city));
```

Str_replace makes `-` spaces and ucwords will camel case the words in the string.

Example:
https://3v4l.org/oZuNB

Comment: Not exactly, sometimes the second word should not have a capital first letter. It's just a default wordpress field something like "category" you give a category name and wordpress also creates a URL-friendly version. And I want to show the value and not the URL-friendly value.

Comment: If it's city names then it should always be camel cased as far as I know. What cases do you mean should not be camel cased?

Comment: I have also this: https://i.ibb.co/0rHDbL3/Schermafbeelding-2018-12-27-om-08-35-30.jpg

Comment: Since there is no rules between the value and what you need then it's quite obvious that you are looking for a solution at the wrong end. You need to either invent a way to get the values correct or look at another place for a solution. Perhaps you could prepend "UC" on words that should be UC'd and so on